# how get array check in datatable with jquery?

Tags: jquery

hello I have a datatable with the checkbox and a button validate, I want when I click on button validate  array lines check display in console array(name, number, address) how to make it help me please.
here is my datatable:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
            <th>nom</th>
            <th>matricule</th>
            <th>adresse</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
            <td>najib</td>
            <td>52</td>
            <td>tihit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
            <td>adil</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td>tagmast</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
            <td>hajar</td>
            <td>72</td>
            <td>tizgui</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

code jquery

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#check_all').on('click', function(e) {
         if($(this).is(':checked',true))  
         {
            $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);  
         } else {  
            $(".checkbox").prop('checked',false);  
         }  
        });
        $('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
            if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length){
                $('#check_all').prop('checked',true);
            }else{
                $('#check_all').prop('checked',false);
            }
         });
        $("#hide").click(function(){
            //
         let value = $('#nbr').val();
         console.log(value);


       });
       });
  </script>
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: `$(this).is(':checked',true)`  `is()` does not take two arguments

Comment: I want when I click on button validate  array check  appears in console

Comment: All the click handler for `check_all` is doing is changing the properties of the checkbox.  It's not logging anything.  In fact the only log you have is when you click the `#hide` element

Comment: i I want to see in my console for exemple array{
(name1, address1, number1)
(name3, address3, number3)
}

Answer (score 1):

This should take care of creating the array:

It ignores the table header row, and checkes if the checkbox is checked for each item.

items is the value of the array.

```
var items = [];
$("tr").each(function(i,r){
    if ( i > 0 && $(r).find("input").first().prop("checked"))
    {
        items.push({"nom": r.cells[1].innerText, "matricule": r.cells[2].innerText, "adresse": r.cells[3].innerText})
    }
});
console.log(items);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u36ta8bz/

Comment: @NajibMarzouk if you can please accept the answer, that would be good